# jQuery Ajax Resource Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest

I have some jQuery code that calls recursively to get some data from a server. It polls the server every 1.5s. Every time it does so, the memory usage goes up - because the responses from each AJAX call are seemingly never discarded.

I've stripped this right down for testing - nothing is done on .done (in the real webapp, something would be written to a DIV), and I've reduced the responses from the server to just a few characters. The timeOut interval makes no difference.

I guess you may ask why do I have to poll so often. It has to be that way. It's an internal webapp polling a server on the LAN for up-to-date status.

Why is this leaking, and how do I correct it? Thanks!

```
(function ajax_poll(){
setTimeout(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: '/responder.php',
  data: { key:value },
  timeout: 5000,
  beforeSend: function(response){
   // do something
  }})
  .done ( function(response){
   // do something
   ajax_poll();
  })
  .fail ( function(response){
   // do something
   ajax_poll();
  });
}, 1500);
})();
```

Comment: You should use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` - it will run the function every 1500 milliseconds, rather than just once, so you won't need to keep calling `ajax_poll`

Comment: Does the memory usage go up in a linear fashion? Does it plateau at some point?

Comment: @Alex Bass. No, I think you're wrong there. setInterval takes no account of delays in retrieving or processing - and requests will just bunch up if things go wrong. Recursive is the way.

Comment: @nnnn - yup, it's linear - in line with the amount of text in the response. My browser (OSX Safari) seems to stop logging at 999 requests. In OSX Chrome, the inspector seems to show the requests going on indefinitely.

Comment: @SimpleSimon totally missed that, sorry you're right. Have you thought about extracting the anonymous function given to `setTimeout`, so that it's not creating a new function every time you execute `ajax_poll`? Then perhaps finishing with `return ajax_poll()` instead of just running it. Perhaps that way it'll be cleared from the memory. Just an idea.